# Cross Site Request Forgery Issue in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error when trying to implement csrf in django. 
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect. (and bla bla bla)
My Views.py shows following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',{'full_name':request.user.username})
def invalid_login(request):
    return render_to_response('invalid_login.html')
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render_to_response('logout.html')
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    args ={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('register.html')
def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

My register.html reflects following:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/', include('article.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django_test.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'django_test.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django_test.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'django_test.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'django_test.views.invalid_login'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'django_test.views.register_user'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'django_test.views.register_success'),
)
```

Please advise. I got cookies enabled in browser.

Comment: is {% csrf_token %} rendered in your template?

Comment: Yes...I've copied the template code as well.

Answer (score 1):

In register.html you need to add csrf token within `<form> </form>` like this:  `{% csrf_token %}`, hopefully it will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best practice but you can add:

```
@csrf_exempt
```

Just above the functions in the view.py file.

See example in django-rest-framework tutorial:
[Writing regular Django views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer)

Comment: It didn't worked rather, now it says @csrf_exempt isn't defined.

Comment: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

Comment: same error after importing csrf_exempt and putting @csrf_exempt just above csrf function.

Comment: Try following this manual:
Cross Site Request Forgery protection https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/